# In Elixir, How can I extract a lambda to a named function when the lambda is in a closure?

Tags: function, lambda, closures, elixir, extract

I have the following closure:

```
  def get!(Item, id) do
    Enum.find(
      @items,
      fn(item) -> item.id == id end
    )
  end
```

As I believe this looks ugly and difficult to read, I'd like to give this a name, like:

```
  def get!(Item, id) do
    defp has_target_id?(item), do: item.id = id
    Enum.find(@items, has_target_id?/1)
  end
```

Unfortunately, this results in:

```
== Compilation error in file lib/auction/fake_repo.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) cannot invoke defp/2 inside function/macro
    (elixir) lib/kernel.ex:5238: Kernel.assert_no_function_scope/3
    (elixir) lib/kernel.ex:4155: Kernel.define/4
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.defp/2
    lib/auction/fake_repo.ex:28: Auction.FakeRepo.get!/2
```

Assuming it is possible, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: how is the first example difficult to read? You can even make it more "beautiful" by wiriting:
`def get!(Item, id) do Enum.find(@items, & &1.id == id) end`

Comment: Or even one-liner: `def get!(Item, id), do: Enum.find(@items, & &1.id == id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted has an enormous amount of syntax errors/glitches. I would suggest you start with getting accustomed to the syntax, rather than trying to make Elixir better by inventing the things that nobody uses.

Here is the correct version that does what you wanted. The task might be accomplished with an anonymous function, although I hardly see a reason to make a perfectly looking idiomatic Elixir look ugly.

```rb
defmodule Foo do
  @items [%{id: 1}, %{id: 2}, %{id: 3}]
  def get!(id) do
    has_target_id? = fn item -> item.id == id end
    Enum.find(@items, has_target_id?)
  end
end

Foo.get! 1
#⇒ %{id: 1}
Foo.get! 4
#⇒ nil
```

Comment: The first method I posted comes from Phoenix in Action.  I left out the module for brevity.  Yes, the task might be accomplished by an anonymous function, but yes that is ugly, which is why I posted this question.  "Item" was part of the original signature for pattern matching though it is irrelevant to this problem.  Line 4 of your solution is enough, though I was somehow under the impression Elixir supports nested functions?

Comment: `def` is a macro as almost everything in Elixir. There is no “nested function” in this context but within this terminology, Elixir does not support nested functions because Erlang does not. I am not sure why you call the standard syntax ugly.

Comment: Having "fn" and "end" in the middle of the expression does not make for good reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
  def get!(Item, id) do
    Enum.find(
      @items,
      &compare_ids(&1, id)
    )
  end

  defp compare_ids(%Item{}=item, id) do
    item.id == id 
  end
```

But, that's equivalent to:

```
Enum.find(
  @items,
  fn item -> compare_ids(item, id) end
)
```

and may not pass your `looks ugly and difficult to read` test.

Comment: Would not `defp compare_ids(%Item{id: id}, id), do: true; defp compare_ids(_, _), do: false` be more explicit? Or, `defp compare_ids(%Item{id: item_id}, id), do: item_id == id`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, Yes. :)

Comment: Not that I'm fond of the name "compare_ids", but wouldn't defp compare_ids(item, id), do: item.id == id  ... be enough?  Is there any advantage to including %Item{} or making separate functions for returning both true and false conditions?

Answer (score 1):

> I was somehow under the impression Elixir supports nested functions?

Easy enough to test:

```
defmodule A do
  def go do

    def greet do
      IO.puts "hello"
    end

    greet()
  end
end
```

Same error:

```
$ iex a.ex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

** (ArgumentError) cannot invoke def/2 inside function/macro
    (elixir) lib/kernel.ex:5150: Kernel.assert_no_function_scope/3
    (elixir) lib/kernel.ex:3906: Kernel.define/4
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.def/2
    a.ex:3: A.go/0
```

Answer (score 1):

> wouldn't:
>
> ```
> defp compare_ids(item, id), do: item.id == id
> ```
>
> be enough? Is there any advantage to including %Item{} or making
>   separate functions for returning both true and false conditions?

What you gain by specifying the first parameter as:

```
func(%Item{} = item, target_id)
```

is that only an Item struct will match the first parameter.  Here is an example:

```
defmodule Item do
  defstruct [:id, :name, :description]
end

defmodule Dog do
  defstruct [:id, :name, :owner]
end

defmodule A do
  def go(%Item{} = item), do: IO.inspect(item.id, label: "id: ")
end
```

In iex:

```
iex(1)> item = %Item{id: 1, name: "book", description: "old"}
%Item{description: "old", id: 1, name: "book"}

iex(2)> dog = %Dog{id: 1, name: "fido", owner: "joe"}        
%Dog{id: 1, name: "fido", owner: "joe"}

iex(3)> A.go item                                            
id: : 1
1

iex(4)> A.go dog                                             
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in A.go/1    

    The following arguments were given to A.go/1:

        # 1
        %Dog{id: 1, name: "fido", owner: "joe"}

    a.ex:10: A.go/1

iex(4)>
```

You get a function clause error if you call the function with a non-Item, and the earlier an error occurs, the better, because it makes debugging easier.

Of course, by preventing the function from accepting other structs, you make the function less general--but because it's a private function, you can't call it from outside the module anyway.  On the other hand, if you wanted to call the function on both Dog and Item structs, then you could simply specify the first parameter as:

```
        |
        V
func(%{}=thing, target_id)
```

then both an Item and a Dog would match--but not non-maps.

What you gain by specifying the first parameter as:

```
             |
             V
func(%Item{id: id}, target_id)
```

is that you let erlang's pattern matching engine extract the data you need, rather than calling `item.id` as you would need to do with this definition:

```
func(%Item{}=item, target_id)
```

In erlang, pattern matching in a parameter list is the most efficient/convenient/stylish way to write functions.  You use pattern matching to extract the data that you want to use in the function body.

Going even further, if you write the function definition like this:

```
                same variable name     
                  |            |
                  V            V
func(%Item{id: target_id}, target_id)
```

then erlang's pattern matching engine not only extracts the value for the `id` field from the Item struct, but also checks that the value is equal to the value of the `target_id` variable in the 2nd argument.

Defining multiple function clauses is a common idiom in erlang, and it is considered good style because it takes advantage of pattern matching rather than logic inside the function body. Here's an erlang example:

```
get_evens(List) -> 
    get_evens(List, []).

get_evens([Head|Tail], Results) when Head rem 2 == 0 -> 
    get_evens(Tail, [Head|Results]);  
get_evens([Head|Tail], Results) when Head rem 2 =/= 0 ->
    get_evens(Tail, Results);
get_evens([], Results) ->
    lists:reverse(Results).
```

Comment: If one wants to call the function on _both_ `Dog` and `Item` _structs_, one should better still disallow maps and other structs: `func(%type{}=thing, target_id) when type in [Dog, Item], do: ...`. Or `func(%_{}=thing, target_id)` to allow _any_ struct, but not maps.